# "coverage run app.py" inside a docker container not creating .coverage file?

Tags: python, docker, containers, dockerfile, coverage.py

System Def:

2012 macbook pro running Sierra, 
Docker version: 17.12.0-ce-mac49 (21995)

The Problem:

I'm having an issue running my python app with "coverage run" in my container.  I'm going to try to explain what i'm doing below.. hopefully it makes sense. Trying to put as much info on what i'm trying to do and what i've done already in here.

Basically my situation is this.  I'm starting a python based (pyramid) web service. It's just a HTTP based API.  Nothing super fancy. I want to get coverage numbers on it for when i run my postman tests against it so I start it by doing "coverage run /path/path/path/app.py" and that works perfectly fine.  I created a .coveragerc to zero in on the sourcecode i want to analyze and everything is perfectly fine, OUTSIDE A CONTAINER.  Trying to get coverage to work INSIDE my containerized version of this app is a different story.

for reference .. here is my Dockerfile with secret stuff masked off with ######### marks

```
FROM ################:latest

# Add files
ADD . / /path/

# Set up Env
ENV GRAPHITE_SERVER=localhost
ENV APP_USER=root
ENV APP_HOME=/path
ENV APP_LOGS=$APP_HOME/logs
ENV PYTHONPATH=#################:$PYTHONPATH
ARG requested_environment=stage1
ARG coverage
ARG log_monitor
ENV COVERAGE=$coverage
ENV LOG_MONITOR=$log_monitor
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$requested_environment
ENV PATH=$APP_HOME/######:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p $APP_LOGS
RUN pip install -r $APP_HOME/requirements.txt
RUN cd $APP_HOME/external-libs/mysql-connector/mysql-connector-python-2.1.2/; python setup.py install

RUN ln -fs /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python

EXPOSE 1234

# start app
ENTRYPOINT $COVERAGE $APP_HOME/path/path/app.py $LOG_MONITOR
```

and my build command is

`docker build . --build-arg requested_environment=stage1 --build-arg log_monitor=noMonitor --build-arg coverage="coverage run" -t stage1-latest`

I want to do the same thing inside the container as i can do outside the container.. meaning..  I want to run the app inside the container with coverage on.  So you'd think that it would be just as simple as building the container as normal, with the entry point which is normally

```
ENTRYPOINT /path/path/path/app.py
changed to
ENTRYPOINT coverage run /path/path/path/app.py
```

BUT apparently not.

If i build the container with an ENTRYPOINT or CMD starting the app..  like these.. and yes i've tried them all..

```
ENTRYPOINT coverage run /path/path/path/app.py
ENTRYPOINT bash -c "coverage run /path/path/path/app.py"
ENTRYPOINT ["bash' "-c","coverage run /path/path/path/app.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["coverage","run","/path/path/path/app.py"]
CMD coverage run /path/path/path/app.py
CMD ["bash' "-c","coverage run /path/path/path/app.py"]
or
CMD ["coverage","run","/path/path/path/app.py"]
```

and then start the container like this

`docker run --name stage1-latest-container-instance -itp 1234:1234 stage1-latest`

or even this in the case of the CMD entries in the dockerfile  (since they're default, and i'm overriding them with this command)

`docker run --name stage1-latest-container-instance -itp 1234:1234 stage1-latest coverage run /path/path/path/app.py`

my app starts perfectly fine.. works no problem..  BUT

no .coverage file is created!   no where in the container's filesystem do i see a .coverage file..

Ok.. trying a diff approach

change the dockerfile to have

```
ENTRYPOINT bash
or
CMD bash
```

rebuild it...

And then run the container with 
`docker run --name stage1-latest-container-instance -itp 1234:1234 stage1-latest`

which gives me a prompt in the docker container.

`[root@ac25fb69bb2e /]#`

Then from another window do this

`docker exec -it stage1-latest-container-instance coverage run /path/path/path/app.py`

or other ways to do this docker exec like

`docker exec -it stage1-latest-container-instance bash -c "coverage run /path/path/path/app.py"`

STILL!  no .coverage file gets created.

Ok.. going a diff approach
I've even created a file called runapp.sh and put the following lines in it

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/path/path && coverage run app.py
```

and then started the container with

`docker run --name stage1-latest-container-instance -itp 1234:1234 stage1-latest /path/runapp.sh`

no .coverage file
then i tried to run the container with just

`docker run --name stage1-latest-container-instance -itp 1234:1234 stage1-latest bash`

and then from another window do

`docker exec -it stage1-latest-container-instance /path/runapp.sh`

still no .container file

ok..  last resort..

go into the prompt that I got after i ran the "docker run" with just "CMD bash" in the dockerfile in interactive mode (-it)..  and start my app with coverage in there manually.

`[root@ac25fb69bb2e /]# coverage run /path/path/path/app.py`

AND AMAZINGLY.. the .coverage file is created no problem....

WHAT THE HECK!
i cannot figure this one out.. I have no idea what's going on... But there seems to be a complete disconnect between a command being executed against the container from outside the container, and a command being executed manually inside a single shell inside the container in terms of whether it can create a file or not.

someone please enlighten me on what i'm doing wrong here.

The only next step i can see is to use the coverage module inside my app itself and add an exception handler for KeyboardInterrupt to save the coverage data when the app is killed off.  But that sucks.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stumbling here from google like I did...

To extend Wolfium's answer, this is caused by docker killing the python process before coverage has written data to it's datafile (or more correctly, python not being able to interpret docker's default `SIGTERM` signal gracefully and just falling in a heap when it gets a `SIGKILL` some seconds later). The quickest way to solve this is to:

- ensure the python process is able to receive a relevant signal. If you're running this inside a shell entrypoint script, you'll probably want to prepend with `exec`, e.g. `exec coverage -m swagger_server`.
- default the stop signal for your image to `SIGINT`, which most python handlers implement: add the line `STOPSIGNAL SIGINT` to your Dockerfile.

The slightly better solution is to make sure your python handler can respond to `SIGTERM` appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what I originally wanted but this is what I ended up having to do to get this all to work right.  Posting this as an answer to my own question in case someone else finds themselves in the same predicament and wants to know how I solved this.

I ended up having to use the coverage api inside my app.py script.  I couldn't figure out for the life of me why using "coverage run" did not work when passing it in as the entrypoint or cmd when running the container.  Still not sure why.  Would love it if someone would share if they know why.

In my app.py i did the following

When it initially starts up i check for a runtime flag being set which i am calling "withcoverage".

```
if withcoverage:
    print "starting code coverage engine"
    import coverage
    os.system("mkdir %s/tmpcoveragedata" % os.environ['HEYTHERE_HOME'])
    coveragedatafile = ".coverage-"+str(int(time.time()))
    cov = coverage.Coverage(data_file=os.environ['APP_HOME']+"/tmpcoveragedata/"+coveragedatafile,config_file=os.environ['APP_HOME']+"/.coveragerc")
    cov.start()
```

then i go on to start up the server as normal.
But I had to add a try: block to catch a KeyboardInterrupt (SIGINT) and save off the coverage before exiting when this happens.   Like so:

```
try:
    # start the server etc.. etc..
    .
    .
    .
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    if withcoverage:
        print "saving coverage stats"
        save_coverage(cov)
        os.system("bash -c 'cd %s/tmpcoveragedata && rm -f .coverage ; cd %s/tmpcoveragedata && ln -s %s .coverage" % (os.environ['APP_HOME'],os.environ['APP_HOME'],coveragedatafile))
        os.system("bash -c 'cd %s/tmpcoveragedata/ && coverage report > %s/tmpcoveragedata/coverage-report-%s.txt'" % (os.environ['APP_HOME'],os.environ['APP_HOME'],coveragedatafile))
    print "exiting program"
    exit()
```

and when i build my container now i mount a volume in the main source repo to that tmpcoveragedata directory inside the container.  Then  the coverage files and reports that are generated when the container receives a SIGINT and exits are saved into that temporary folder, which is mapped to an appropriate coverage data store on the machine running the container.

here's my docker run command

```
docker run --name stage1-latest-container-instance -d -v /app_home/coveragedata:/app_home/tmpcoveragedata -p 1234:1234 stage1-latest
```

And this is now working..  it will run the app with coverage..  save off the coverage on exit with a SIGINT.

one caveat though.  when stopping the container a simple

```
docker stop <container-name>
```

will not suffice.   I needed to do the following so that the app would see the KeyboardInterrupt when my automation stops the container.

```
docker kill --signal=SIGINT stage1-latest-container-instance
```

hope this helps anyone else dealing with this out there.

Answer (score 0):

Great info and details, explaining and showing workarounds.
It helped me a lot in the right direction.

Root cause is when running in docker your patched covered service is running and coverage running as a entrypoint in docker does not save until finished running.

So if you are able to break like you do it worked, same for me.
Just I am using Flask and I found that the dev server it uses capture key interruptions exceptions and I had no way to take the service server under coverage shut down.
Finally I found a way to get a route that signal the flask dev server down from inside and it worked like a charm as you show me at first place.

Thanks a lot for sharing...

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of @Andy-T's answer, I found that Python itself (or perhaps only the Flask dev server) wasn't gracefully shutting down in response to a SIGTERM signal, even outside docker. So, by registering a signal handler for SIGTERM, I was able to call `sys.exit()` which gave coverage.py a chance to write out the data.

Here's my app.py file:

```
import sys
import signal
from flask import Flask


def exit_cleanly(signal_number, stackframe):
    sys.exit()


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_cleanly)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Key points here:

- The `signal` module from the standard library allows you to register functions as "callbacks" when python receives a certain signal from the operating system.
- `signal.SIGTERM` is the default signal sent on linux and macos by the `kill` command
- `sys.exit` without arguments allowed the python interpreter to shutdown, going through all the normal cleanup steps -- including the coverage.py code registered to run at exit

Then, inside my (macos or linux) terminal I ran these commands to provide coverage data *without docker*:

```
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip3 install Flask
coverage run -m flask run &> /tmp/flask.log &
curl http://localhost:5000/
kill "$(ps -ef | grep 'coverage run' | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }')"
coverage report
```

Details:

- 1st two lines are totally optional, but recommended to isolate dependecies into a virtual environment (not relevant to OP)
- `coverage run -m flask run &> /tmp/flask.log &` puts the stderr/stdout into a file in the /tmp directory so that the terminal doesn't get cluttered and unreadable (`&> /tmp/flask.log`). It also sends the process into the background (the trailing `&`)
- `curl http://localhost:5000/` -- this just makes a request as a lightweight test of the Flask app. You could replace this with your actual test run (aka py.test or behave or whatever)
- `kill "$(ps -ef | grep 'coverage run' | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }')"` -- searches through running processes with `ps -ef`, then filters down to only processes that have `coverage run` in it then removes itself (grep -v means remove matching lines), then finds the 2nd field with the PID. Finally, kill sends SIGTERM to the PID. So, this should cause the `exit_cleanly()` callback to fire and teardown the flask process.
- `coverage report` just prints a summary to the terminal so you can see if this worked

To run this inside docker, I wrap up all this into a bash script and make it the entry point of the docker container. Here's a repository which hash all this working and integrated with CircleCI + Codecov as a boilerplate example:
https://github.com/brycefisher/coveragepy-flask